# Binary Options hedge Forex position

Tags: fx, hedging, binary-options

if I am short GBPJPY and it start to jump up, instead of closing it, could I use Binary Options to long it immediately after jump up? So I could hedge current Forex position if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hedge a short why don't you buy a call option instead? Have a look at  these [option strategies for hedging](http://www.optiontradingtips.com/strategies/)